# git failure on OSX - trying to pull the code from my own repository

Tags: git, macos

ALL,

Trying to pull the latest code from my own repository I am getting following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/oneeyeman1/dbhandler.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

This is the first time I'm getting this error.

Trying to access it from the browser I have no issues.

I'm trying it on the OSX 10.8 with the freshly installed git client:

```
MyMac:dbhandler igorkorot$ /usr/local/git/bin/git --version git
version 2.3.5
```

Does anyone know how can I fix it?

TIA!!

[EDIT]

I updated git to the latest version (2.16.3), but this one failed to start:

```
MyMac:dbhandler igorkorot$ /usr/local/git/bin/git pull
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

error: fetch died of signal 5
```

Any idea?

[/EDIT]

Comment: I don't know how to help off-hand, but I might be able to point you in the right direction. That's not a git error, that's an SSL error. Perhaps it's a temporary issue (Git may have updated their SSL cert), perhaps you need to upgrade OpenSSL (or whatever SSL client you have on your machine), or perhaps you're going through a proxy that is intercepting your connection and fudging the certificate.

Comment: how did you update?

Comment: @avigil, I downloaded the file, unpack it, ran the dmg file and went thru the installation wizard.

Comment: you could try updating using homebrew- may be easier than trying to track down whatever is wrong with your install

Answer (score 0):

Github updated to some new crypto recently and forgot to tell people about it so some clients were not updated in time.

Update your git client(s).

https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/

Comment: @JoePhilips, I updated the "git" but now getting different error. Please see the edit for the OP. Thx.

Comment: @Igor I have no idea. That's an entirely different question than the original